# How to SELECT 2 joined tables in one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 1 master_table and 2 sub_tables. I want the join the 3 columns together (but the problem is the 2 sub_tables do not have any column that share the same value) and then SELECT * based on 2 different columns from the 2 sub_tables.

I've searched and tried many ways of coding, but couldn't find a solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM (master INNER JOIN sub_1 ON master.id=sub_1.id WHERE sub_1.column_1 = 'Y')
AND (master INNER JOIN sub_2 ON master.id=sub_2.id WHERE sub_2.column_2 = 'Y')
ORDER BY master.id
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
***  Finally, solved. See the solution at the bottom of this post. ***
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

===========

Edit: explain more about my data, problem and MySQL code

I have 3 tables stored in MySQL as follow

```
Master_table: regist
------------------------------------------
| reg_no | firstname | lastname | submit |
------------------------------------------
|   1    |  first_A  |  last_A  |   N    |
|   2    |  first_B  |  last_B  |   A    |
|   3    |  first_C  |  last_C  |   P    |
|   4    |  first_D  |  last_D  |   P    |
|   5    |  first_E  |  last_E  |   A    |
|   6    |  first_F  |  last_F  |   N    |
|   7    |  first_G  |  last_G  |   N    |
|   8    |  first_H  |  last_H  |   A    |
------------------------------------------

Sub_1: sub_A                       Sub_2: sub_P
------------------------------        ------------------------------
| reg_no | A_title | reply_A |        | reg_no | P_title | reply_P |
------------------------------        ------------------------------
|   2    |   222   |    Y    |        |   3    |   333   |    N    |
|   5    |   555   |    N    |        |   4    |   444   |    Y    |
|   8    |   888   |    Y    |        ------------------------------
------------------------------
```

I want to create a query that gives result like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| reg_no | firstname | lastname | submit | A_title | reply_A | P_title | reply_P |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2    |  first_B  |  last_B  |   A    |   222   |    Y    |         |         |
|   8    |  first_H  |  last_H  |   A    |   888   |    Y    |         |         |
|   4    |  first_D  |  last_D  |   P    |         |         |   444   |    Y    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

or

-----------------------------------------------------------
| reg_no | firstname | lastname | submit | title |  reply |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   2    |  first_B  |  last_B  |   A    |  222  |   Y    |
|   8    |  first_H  |  last_H  |   A    |  888  |   Y    |
|   4    |  first_D  |  last_D  |   P    |  444  |   Y    |
-----------------------------------------------------------

$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM (regist INNER JOIN sub_A ON regist.reg_no = sub_A.reg_no WHERE sub_A.reply_A = 'Y')
    AND  (regist INNER JOIN sub_P ON regist.reg_no = sub_P.reg_no WHERE sub_P.reply_P = 'Y')
    ORDER BY regist.reg_no";
```

Expected outcome: 
ECHO personal data of all registrants who got reply as 'Y'

```
if($row['submit']=="A") $title = $row['A_title'];
elseif($row['submit']=="P") $title = $row['P_title'];

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['reg_no']." / ".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']." / ".$title."<br>";
}
```

Problem: my SELECT code resulted in error. The code from @GMB and @Rogue didn't error, but echo give nothing.

If it is not possible to code a query as I want, I will just modify the column names (sub_1.reply_A and sub_2.reply_P) to be the same and change the input code in other webpages. However, it would be best if there is a way because I don't know whether the 'reply' columns were used somewhere else.

========================

Solution: a little modification from @Rogue code

```
SELECT *
FROM master
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_1
   ON master.id=sub_1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_2
   ON master.id=sub_2.id
WHERE sub_1.column_1 = 'Y'
   OR sub_2.column_2 = 'Y'
ORDER BY master.id
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to give you good comments/answers all we can do is making educated guesses without example data and expected results.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) how to provide example data and expected results.

Comment: I'm sorry that my first post is not properly explained. I didn't get used to the forum system and I had to leave soon because it was already very late at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want simple `JOIN`s between these 3 tables ?

```
SELECT m.*, s1.*, s2.*
FROM master m
INNER JOIN sub_1 s1 ON m.id=s1.id AND s1.column_1 = 'Y'
INNER JOIN sub_2 s2 ON m.id=s2.id AND s2.column_2 = 'Y'
ORDER BY m.id;
```

If you have master records that may not exist in both sub tables, you can switch to `LEFT JOIN` to avoid filtering them out.

Guidelines :

- typical syntax is `SELECT ... FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ... INNER JOIN table3 ON...`
- better put all conditions related to a JOINed table in the `ON` clause of the join rather than in the `WHERE` clause
- avoid `SELECT *` : be specific about the columns you want to select
- use table aliases to make the query easier to read

Comment: Are you sure the result is the one requested?
OP wants records from the first join AND the records from the second join, while this query (correct me if I'm wrong) takes only the ones satisfying both rules.

Comment: @Marco : agreed - I updated my answer to mention the possible usage of `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: This one sounds much better :)

Comment: @GMB : Thank you for your quick response. No error appear from your code, but no result come out from the query. Unfortunately, it is now very late at my country. I will try to explain more about my code, my data and my goal later.

Ps. It is my first time post a thread here. I'm sorry that I was unable to properly post the thread. I have to learn more about how to use this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You're a little off syntactically:

```
SELECT *
FROM master
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_1
   ON master.id=sub_1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_2
   ON master.id=sub_2.id
WHERE sub_1.column_1 = 'Y'
   AND sub_2.column_2 = 'Y'
ORDER BY master.id
```

Personally I would recommend not using `SELECT *` and only grabbing the data you will need. As for determining what join to use, I like to link to [CodingHorror's blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) in these times.

Edit: swapped INNER to LEFT OUTER, per OP's update

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. No error appear from your code, but no result come out from the query. I have explained more about my issue in the OP. Thanks

Comment: What you're looking for is called a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (not `INNER`). The link in my answer explains the differences but it has to do with which data is included and excluded

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. After I tried a lot based on your code, I finally success with a little modification of your code. It works after changing AND to OR in WHERE clause. Thank you very much, Rogue.